# How to get parent_id count?

Tags: laravel-5.8

Users table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('referral_code')->nullable();
        $table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
        $table->string('mobile')->unique();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Order table

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('oreders', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->bigInteger('product_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

I tried `first` and `whereHas('user')` replaced it

```
$orderCount = Order::whereHas('user')->withCount('parent_id')->get();
return $orderCount;
```

I get this error.

> Call to undefined method App\Order::parent_id() (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\site\bazar\resources\views\Admin\master.blade.php)

Comment: Are you trying to get the number of order for one user? And what's `parent_id`?

Comment: Each user comes in for registration. And it will enter the referral code marketer. And the user enters the marketing code. And it's stored in the parent_id

Comment: I have added the use case (based on assumption of what I understand)  for _"And marketers can see how many people bought their code"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to define the relationship in your models `App\User` and `App\Order`

**App/User.php**

```
class User extends Model
{

    public function orders()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Order::class);
    }

    public function parent()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'parent_id');
    }

    public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'parent_id');
    }

}
```

**App/Order.php**

```
class Order extends Model
{

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }
}
```

I do believe you want to count the number of order for a user.
But first of all, we will fix some issues / I'm suspecting you have.

- Table name `orders` is called `oreders`
- You don't need to verify if an order has a user `Order::whereHas('user')` since `$table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();` is not nullable. It means an order cannot exists without a user.
- Not an issue but a suggestion `$table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();` can be simplified with `$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');`

Now the interesting part

```
$orderCount = Order::whereHas('user')->withCount('parent_id')->get();
return $orderCount;
```

In my understand you're trying to get the number of orders of of a parent of the user. I will show you some use case that may help your understanding.

```
// Get the total number of orders
$orderCount = Order::count();

// Get the total number of orders of a user
$userOrderCount = $user->orders()->count();

// Include the number of orders in the user attributes
$user = User::withCount('orders')->find($userId); // notice 'order' is, in fact `orders()` from the App\User methods

// Include the number of orders in the parent attributes
$parent = User::withCount('orders')->find($user->parent_id);

// Number of orders of the parent
$parentOrderCount = Order::where('user_id', $user->parent_id)->count();

// Edit: As you commented, you also want to know "The marketers can see how many people bought their code"
// I'm assuming this is the number of children (I have added the relation in the model above)
$childrenCount = $user->children()->count()
```

Note : when you do `Order::where('user_id', $user->parent_id)->count();` you don't need to verify that the user has a parent first. `parent_id` will return null and `user_id` cannot be `null`. So it will just return `0`

Comment: I don't know. The `User` you want information to. Eg. `$user = User::find(1);` or `$userId = 1`; or  `$user = auth()->user()`  or `$userId = auth()->id()`

Comment: Also `$userOrderCount = $user->orders()->count();` can also be done like this `$userOrderCount = Order::where('user_id', $userId)->count();`

Comment: the `$parent = User::withCount('orders')->find($user->parent_id);` not working

Comment: What doesn't work ? You have an error ? Is $parent null ? Is count attribute 0 but should have order? Note that in this scenario, the user must have a parent. Otherwise $parent will be null